# Computationally efficient means of determining distance in the Skorohod Topology?

Tags: probability-theory, algorithms, metric-spaces, skorohod-space

I have two functions f and g in a computer.  Domain 1...N.  I'd like to compute their distance using the [Skorohod Topology](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Skorokhod_space) in an efficient manner.  (I first ran across this metric many years ago in Billingsley's excellent book, "Convergence of Probability Measures").  Does such an algorithm exist?